How can I tag a value as not expected to be null?
I have a function that's correctly specified as returning a potentially-null object. My code calls that function but in a way where it isn't going to return a null.
MyClass? MyFunction(string x);
/* ... */
var myObject = MyFunction("Never return null.");
myObject.MyMemberFunctionOfMyClass();

Visual Studio (correctly) flags the use of myObject as a "possible null reference". I know that it will never be null but the compiler doesn't know that.
Is there a way to flag this as a known can't-be-null? I know I could add a test for null, but that would be duplicating the test-for-null/throw-NullReferenceException code that the compiler will insert anyway and my function is very neat and tidy without it. I'd also rather not use the #pragma that turns off the warning as I want to keep the warning for other values.
I'd prefer some way of wrapping up a single value in a cloak of "This value won't be null. Continue as you were."
var myObject = MyFunction("Never return null.").NotNull();

Does such a thing exist?

There is NotNullAttribute

var myObject = MyFunction("Never return null.")!; or myObject!.MyMemberFunctionOfMyClass();

Wait... if it cannot return null, why does it return MyClass? and not MyClass ? That kind of counter-intuitive.

! is null forgiving that will get rid if your underlines (if you are certain it's not null)

You still might considering making your code defensive. What if that other method changes to return null?

@Fildor more than one thing can call it and consume in different ways. In some cases it can be null, in other cases you may have already dealt with the possibility of null.

@Fildor - The real world equivalent of MyFunction is a standard library function that returns null if it doesn't recognise the value in the string parameter. Because I'm calling it with a fixed value that should always work, it won't return null in my case. (And if it does, a NullReferenceException is what I'd want to happen anyway.)

In that case, I'd wrap it. I personally prefer bool TryX( out var value, string arg ) - pattern for this. There you could use [NotNullWhen(true)] on the value... if that helps.

@shingo The ! tag was exactly what I was looking for. If you want to make that an answer I'll give you the green-tick-points.

Oh, then Rob was right. Mind that this works only once. Meaning: if you call that function in another place, you'll have to use the null-forgiving operator there, too (or deal with it differently).

If you are really sure something is not null, and you don't want to pay a performance cost for a redundant null check, you can always use ! to suppress it.
var myObject = MyFunction("Never return null.")!;

Which you might choose to put in a wrapper function with an explanation.
If the function really can sometimes return null, it may also be possible to annotate the condition that the return may or may not be null, for example.
    [return: NotNullIfNotNull(nameof(input))]
    public static string? Foo(string? input)
    {
        if (input == null) return null;
        else return input + "bar";
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        string a = Foo(null); // Warning
        string b = Foo("hello"); // No warning
        string? c = Foo(null); // No warning
        string d = Foo(b); // No warning
        string e = Foo(c); // Warning
}

However the possibilities for these are fairly limited.
Another option without just suppressing with a ! would be to make a version of the function that does not return null, and throws (or maybe asserts if really want to avoid release performance costs) if given inputs might result in null. In the simplest case this might be a wrapper. Giving more protection than just silencing the warning.
public static string? MaybeNull(string input) // 3rd party thing you can't change
{
    if (input.Length < 5) return null;
    else return input;
}
public static string NeverNull(string input)
{
    if (input.Length < 5) throw new ArgumentException("Must be at least 5 characters.", nameof(input));
    string? ret = MaybeNull(input);
    Debug.Assert(ret != null);
    return ret!;
}
public static string NeverNull2(string input)
{
    string? ret = MaybeNull(input);
    if (ret == null) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid input.", nameof(input));
    return ret;
}


Confirmed that a ! tagged null value will throw a NullReferenceException if used, which is exactly what I want to happen.
